# Exception not getting thrown when no input is given

Tags: java, exception

```
class Ex_ex
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

         if (args[0].equals("first"))
             if (args[1].equals("second")) //Expected exception here LINE1
             {
                 System.out.println("first..second");
             }
             else 
             {
                System.out.println("nothing "+ args[1]);
             }

     }
}
```

I executed this program from command line 
I gave the following command

"java Ex_ex test"

test is args[0] and args[1] was not given.

I thought I will get a runtime exception at LINE 1 as it tries it access non existent args[1] ...but I did not get an exception.

Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName. You should only improve formatting of the code, and not the code itself. Seems like you added the braces inside the inner if-else block. That was not there earlier.

Comment: @RohitJain ok, but i did made sure there will not change the logic, just clearer way to write it

Comment: @NoIdeaForName. Yeah but you should not do edit the question. I was going to write some point about that in my answer. But after your edit, that point wouldn't make sense now.

Comment: @RohitJain understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 2nd `if` statement is inside the 1st `if` statement. So, it will be executed only when the first `if` condition evaluates to `true`.

Since `args[0]` you are passing is `test`, it will fail the outer `if` condition, and the inner `if` will not be executed, and hence no exception thrown.

Try executing your code like:

```
java Ex_ex first
```

Comment: Yep...careless of me..Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`args[0]` didn't equal "first", so it didn't go into the inner `if` statement. You do understand that those are nested `if` statements, right?

Answer (score 1):

because it does not pass the first if statement

```
if (args[0].equals("first"))
```

so it doesn't get to the second if statement and thus not getting thrown